# Windows 7 hotkey to focus running application

Tags: windows-7, hotkeys, alt-tab

I know how to hotkey an application from the Taskbar, but if the application is already running, and I don't want to start *another* instance of that application, is there a way to hot key to it? I know I can do win-T if the application in question is the first on the task bar, but again, that starts a new instance. If you have a program that won't start another instance, that works great, as they will just focus on the running instance. I just want to quickly get to the already running instance.

Is there a solution for that in Windows, or an add on program that can help? It would be best if I could pick the key...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For my computers <kbd>Win</kbd>+<number> (where <number> is the place of the icon from left or top) switches you to the program and <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<number> should open another instance of the same program.

Comment: Actually, Win + <number> seems to "make the app listed in that place on the taskbar be focused". So, if you have IE pinned to your taskbar in the first spot, and it isn't running then Win + 1 launches it. If it IS running, then it brings it to focus. And since whatever else is running is next in line on the task bar, that does in fact work for my issue. Thank you!